# Prism 5.0 External 3rd party dll

Tags: c#, dll, prism-5

so I am a bit confused on how to word this...

The program we are using utilizes a third party DLL developed by a vendor. This DLL is not a prism module its a basic DLL.

When adding this regularly as c# requires it fails to initialize the module that uses it throwing a key not found error.

When moving this DLL to the modules directory it will throw an exception as the DLLis not compatible (using MEF directory discovery of Modules)

When trying to embed this DLL as an Interop type it throws the regular interop errors as the DLL was not built with this in mind.

**so I guess my question is. What is the best way to add an external DLLas a dependency to a module without having access to the source code of the DLL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the module using the external library needs to have it referenced properly but for run-time the library needs to be accessible in the shell (startup project) executing folder